# subsapce of f(T)V T -invariant

Tags: linear-algebra

On a vector space $X$, choose a nonzero element $v \in X$ and a linear map $T : V \to V$.  $f(T)v$ is the space generated by $v, T(v), T^2(v),\dots$

I think any subspace of $f(T)v$ is also $T$-invariant, but cannot prove it.
Could anyone help?

Comment: You have $v$ and $V$. Do you mean $f(T)v$ or $f(T)V$?  If so, then how do we choose $v$?  Also, please [format your math correctly](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: oh sorry I will conrrect it

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* true that any subspace of $f(T)v$ is $T$-invariant.

**Counterexample:** 
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad v = \pmatrix{1\\0}
$$
The subspace of $f(T)v = \Bbb R^2$ that is generated by $v$ is 
$$
\left\{\pmatrix{t\\0} \mid t \in \Bbb R \right\}
$$
which is not $T$-invariant.

Comment: @daw the subspace generated by $v$ is 
$$
\left\{\pmatrix{t\\0} \mid t \in \Bbb R \right\}$$
which is certainly not $T$-invariant.